# Testcafe cucumber reporter video recording

Tags: ffmpeg, cucumber, e2e-testing, testcafe, video-recording

Steps to record test video in Testcafe is nicely explained [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/screenshots-and-videos.html#default-path-patterns). I am using [cucumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-cucumber-json) to publish the reports. Once the report is published, a link to the screenshot is provided at errored scenarios. But unable to find a way to provide a link to the video on those errored scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

[TestRunInfo](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/reporter-methods.html#testruninfo-object) doesn't contain information about recorded videos. 
A reporter is not able to get information about recorded videos from TestCafe. You can try to add the recorded video as custom attachments, but it's not flexible because you need to know the full paths of the recorded videos. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4160) in the TestCafe repository on GitHub to add information about recorded videos to the 'TestRunInfo' object.